zsh curly bracket command expansion with homebrew command
In zsh, the commands can be expanded with curly brackets. For example:
head text{1,2,3}.txt

which will display the first 10 lines of text1.txt, text2.txt and text3.txt.
However, when I execute the following command:
brew {update,upgrade}

suppose it should run identical as:
brew update && brew upgrade

However, the command outputs:
Error: This command updates brew itself, and does not take formula names.
Use `brew upgrade upgrade` instead.

What is my mistake?

One way to diagnose things like this is to prepend a print command. Try print -r -- head text{1,2,3}.txt and print -r -- brew {update,upgrade} to see what the commands look like after brace expansion.

I didn't know I can do so. This trick is handy! How can I make the brew update && brew upgrade command shorter?

Put this in your shell initialization file: alias bu='brew update && brew upgrade'

nice idea of using alias !

Brace expansion rewrites the command with the arguments separated by spaces. It doesn’t insert any operators or duplicate the whole command. You seem to be thinking of it as if it analyzed the command to figure out what you intended.
